# Display date in YYYYMM format

Tags: mysql, sql

Needs to display the date in format 'YYYYMM' instead it is displaying in for of 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
declare @five date, @fiveend date
set @five = dateadd(year,-5,datefromparts(year(getdate()),1,1))
set @fiveend = datefromparts(year(getdate()),12,1)

select @fiveend
select @five
```

Comment: MySQL? Are you sure

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server (MS SQL) one. But MS SQL <> MySQL.

Comment: *Needs to display the date in format 'YYYYMM'* In SQL Server use, for example, `YEAR(your_date) * 100 + MONTH(your_date)` (returns integer value) or FORMAT(your_date, 'yyyyMM') (returns string).

Answer (score 0):

You must apply DATE_FORMAT function to get your desired format, as follow:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@fiveend, '%Y%m');
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@five, '%Y%m');
```

You can see [here](https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-date_format/)

Comment: DATE_FORMAT does not work on MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select format(@fiveend(), 'yyyymm')
select format(@fiveend(), 'yyyymm')
```

Comment: Format works on mysql different

Comment: Added the format one, it does not work.  It should display 202201 but it is displaying 202200 and 201700

Comment: hm, interesting, in that case try this:
`SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), @five, 112)
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), @fiveend, 112)`